# Absolute path in Symfony1.4

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I am looking for how to get *absolute path using* **symfony1.4**. If any one help me with this issue.
for example,

```
 <img src="'.public_path('logo.jpg').'" alt="html logo" style="width:70px;height:70px;">
```

The path which i get is like,

```
/erp/symfony/web/logo.jpg
```

but what i want is like,

```
 C:/wamp/www/erp/symfony/web/logo.jpg
```

I need this path to export my image using DOMPDF.

I would really appreciate them.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how much you have worked on your codes...

Comment: this is my code,<img src="'.public_path('logo.jpg').'" alt="html logo" style="width:70px;height:70px;">, it shows, /erp/symfony/web/logo.jpg, not absolute path, but i need absolute path to export using DOMPDF.

Comment: @NimatullahRazmjo : Update the code in your question, Not in comment

Comment: @NimatullahRazmjo Can you try this directly ? `<img src="web/logo.jpg" alt="html logo" style="width:70px;height:70px;">` ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen, I have tried, but its not working. even it not bring the image into my browser.

Comment: Just asking for instance. It works if you contact it directly `C:/wamp/www/` ?

Comment: Yes, Its working if i give C:/wamp/www/erp/symfony/web/uploads/logo.jpg. to my path

Answer (score 1):

You should use

> sfConfig::get("sf_web_dir")

which brings you the absolute dir of your web path.

In your case it will be :

```
<img src="<?php echo sfConfig::get("sf_web_dir")?>/logo.jpg" alt="html logo" style="width:70px;height:70px;">
```